# How to detect a call ended in twilio studio

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml, twilio-studio

Is it possible to detect a call ended in studio?

I have a studio flow that performs a call to a number (this is the first step and it is configured with the make outgoing call widget). The problem is that i am not able to detect if the call ends once the call is connected, the widget itself allows detecting if busy or failed.

I want to know if it is possible to detect call end event so i am able to react to this in my app. Or be able to start an outbound call using call resource api and after the call is connected guide my user through the flow steps (I only have a phone number if that matters)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Studio does not expose the StatusCallback so you are aware of the status of the call. You can build this outside Studio and configure the StatusCallback URL to be alerted to the call state. You can fine more details here, [Set StatusCallback on an outbound call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/make-calls?code-sample=code-set-statuscallback-on-an-outbound-call&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=3.x).